# Post return 405 method not allowed. Make Get instead of Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

when I make a call via httpclient I receive a strange behavior. the answer is 405 method not allowed. checking on fidler the request is reported as a GET. How can this be possible?

```
private HttpResponseMessage Save(string value1, string value2, int value3)
        {
            var jsonModel = new CreateCustomerRequest()
            {
                Value1= value1,
                Value2= value2,
                Value3= value3
            };
            var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonModel);
            var baseurl = configuration.GetValueFromAppSettings("baseUrl");
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var payLoad = new StringContent(serializeObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                return client.PostAsync("api/Customer", payLoad).Result;
            }
        }
```

[fiddler result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNaO9.png)

Comment: Are you in control of the target URL?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't seeing a POST request first which gives response of "302 Redirect" and then a GET request ?

Comment: Can you share the bit of API code which you have configured for POST action? Are you able to call the API from post man?

Comment: Via postman the call go fine.  It's a really strange thing. I tried the code I posted in another console application and I received 200. could it be a missing import of a nuget pakage?

Comment: [FYI - you're using HttpClient incorrectly](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) although it isn't the source of your current problem.

Comment: I suspect @OrelEraki is right. HttpClient follows redirects by default, and post/redirect/get is obviously a very common pattern (although not so much with APIs but who knows)

Comment: @ToddMenier Thanks for the reply. Looking better on fiddler the call in post returns 302.